# Create LMDB for Imageset

Tags: machine-learning, caffe, pycaffe, lmdb

I'm quite new to Caffe framework. I'm trying to create LMDB database for face image dataset. I downloaded face-image-set from [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/openimages/2017_07/images_2017_07.tar.gz) . This dataset is in csv format. Anyway i downloaded the images. The csv file contains face and person bounding coordinates in each images. How will i create LMDB-db for these images?

I saw this command -

```
~$ GLOG_logtostderr=1 $CAFFE_ROOT/build/tools/convert_imageset \
    --resize_height=200 --resize_width=200 --shuffle  \
    /path/to/jpegs/ \
    /path/to/labels/train.txt \
    /path/to/lmdb/train_lmdb
```

But i dont know how to create this- /labels/train.txt. or what does the it mean. i saw the SPACE. I don't know what this number means.

Only labels, i want is person and face. So how to create train.txt ? From there how to create the LMDB?. Please help find the right answer, Please..

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this [one](https://github.com/jinfagang/kitti-ssd) and got some results.